# How to apply AddEventListener to created element?

Tags: javascript

I need your help I working on an application and I'm a beginner in JS
I want to apply `addEventListener` on a created element

```js
const i = document.querySelector(".fas");
li.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-times"></i>`;
i.addEventListener("click", removeTask);

function removeTask(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    li.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

It's not working can anybody help me, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `i` is not a created element, it's an existing element that you selected with `querySelector`.

Answer (score 0):

You used `li` when you should have used `i`. I'm not sure if your variable `li` is defined somewhere else, but that might be causing the problem. Otherwise, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
const fas = document.getElementByClassName("fas");
li.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-times"></i>`;
i.addEventListener("click", function(){ removeTask(e));
function removeTask(e) {
e.preventDefault();
li.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to click on the times icon and apply line through to your li element.

In your case as in mine, i element as an innerHTML of another element this means it exists !

Here is a simple example below

```js
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>"

document.querySelector("i").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  console.log("Hello Stackoverflow")
  //your code here for callback
})
```

```css
i{
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div>
  Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want, thanks much appreciated

Comment: What I was missing is that i worked when I directly make document.querySelector("")